# How do you access AVCaptureConnections formed by addInput and addOutput calls to AVCaptureSession?

Tags: avcapturesession

If I instantiate an AVCaptureSession, and add video inputs and outputs using addInput and addOutput, supposedly instances of AVCaptureConnection are being formed automatically, "greedily" as the Apple documentation states.

I'd like to access the connection, so I can alter the videoOrientation property.

How do I access the connections? I would have thought something like captureSession.connections but there's nothing of the sort.

Answer (score 1):

I alter my videoOrientation like this:

```
let stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
var previewLayer :AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

let vidConnection :AVCaptureConnection = stillImageOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

stillImageOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).videoOrientation = previewLayer!.connection.videoOrientation

stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection
```